# Need XPath for button within section

Tags: java, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I'm using Selenium to test a webpage, and I can't seem to figure out how to write the XPath for the Next button.

There are multiple Next buttons in the code, however they're in different sections. The one I'm trying to test has the following code:

```
<section class="col-md-12">
   <input type = "submit" value ="Next">
```

If I use the following command it gives me an unidentified element error.

```
//input[@type = 'submit']
```

OR

```
//input[@value = 'Next']
```

This is probably because it's viewing the other next buttons in the page. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @kjhughes I've made the changes

Comment: I've rolled back the edits which ***completely*** change the question.  Ask a new question if you have to.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select the `input` elements (with `@value` attribute value equal to `Next`) anywhere beneath `section` elements (with `@class` attribute value equal to `col-md-12`):

```
//section[@class='col-md-12']//input[@value='Next']
```

Comment: @khjhughes I wrote the code from memory the first time I posted the question. I edited the question to the proper code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question you've asked "from memory" is answered correctly here.  If you need help on the (now rolled-back) version of your question, please ask a new one.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not allowed to ask another question until tomorrow, that's why I edited the question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: You can improve your question asking by *not* "asking from memory" in this manner and reading [ask] so that you won't have problems in the future having your [asking rate be limited](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited).  Thanks.